# InputTransparent=true does not work in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

From [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InputTransparent/) link.

> false if the element should receive input; true if element should not receive input and should, instead, pass inputs to the element below. Default is false.

What I want is, the Entry field must not be allowed to receive input from user.

`InputTransparent=true` works well in iOS but doesn't work in Android, it still allows the user to give input.

I tried `IsEnabled=false` but that changes the look of my Entry field and I don't want that.

Is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0):

InputTransparent do not work for Android. I created simply render for StackLayout:

in PCL project:

```
public class StackLayoutAdd :StackLayout
{
}
```

in Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(StackLayoutAdd),   typeof(StackLayoutAddCustom))] 
.....
public class StackLayoutAddCustom : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
{
    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        return !Element.InputTransparent;
    }
}
```

I use this in my xaml:

```
 <StackLayoutAddCustom InputTransparent={Binding IsReadOnly}>
   <Editor />
  ....
 </StackLayoutAddCustom>
```

This is work for children control.

Comment: I just did this with a checkbox renderer and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083871/method-ontouchevent-not-being-called) : 
this fires continuously while touching the screen, so applying custom renderer and override the **DispatchTouchEvent**

```
 public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (Element.InputTransparent)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        }
```